# I have error with c function

Tags: c

I am new for C, I try to write code and I need to deal with string. I need to cut the first word from string, and I need to return the the word and the rest of the string.

I wrote this code to cut the first word but I am getting error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
anyone know why, how to fix it?
 symbol is equal to " ".

```
char * cut(char *str, char *symbol)
{
int i=0;    
static char *temp;
  while (str[i]!=symbol[0])
  {
     temp[i]=str[i];
     i++;  
  }
printf("temp %s\n ",temp);
return temp;
}
```

Comment: `temp` is uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Also, consider what happens if the string in `symbol` is nowhere in the `str`.  What happens with your `while` loop?

Comment: Also, you need to null-terminate the string you're copying into `temp`.

Comment: ..and it's not thread-safe 'cos static.

Comment: The uninitialized temp is something which you should have spotted while stepping through with your debugger.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, please indent consistently.   Indent after every open brace '{' indent before every closing brace '}'  Never use tabs for indenting (suggest 4 spaces per each indent level) as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Note: 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows many indent levels across the page.

Comment: regarding this line: `temp[i]=str[i];`  this results in undefined behaviour because `temp` is not pointed to a segment of allocated memory.  Undefined behaviour means most anything can happen, including a seg fault event.

Comment: I need to call this function couple time. the only way I tried and work is     static char temp[30]; ,But when I call it in the second time the function keep a previous value for temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the posted code contains a few problems.  including undefined behaviour.

Caveat: this code assumes the parameter `str` points to a NUL terminated string.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // strlen(), malloc()

char * cut(char *str, char *symbol)
{
    char *temp = NULL;
    if( NULL == (temp = malloc( strlen(str)+1) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    int i;
    for(i=0; str[i] && str[i] !=symbol[0]; i++)
    {
        temp[i]=str[i];
    }

    // terminate string
    temp[i] = '\n';

    printf("temp %s\n",temp);
    return temp;
}
```

However, the question says to return the first word AND the rest of the string which neither the posted code nor my answer implement

Comment: Thank you. It is work perfectly as I want. I am trying to get the first word then I can deal with the rest of the string in similar way in the previous answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me what does this statement do?   `temp = malloc( strlen(str)+1);`

Comment: Please read the man page for `malloc()`  in general, malloc allocates the desired number of bytes of memory from the `heap` and returns a pointer to that allocated memory.  the `strlen(str)` returns the number of bytes, before the NUL byte in the `str[]` array,  The +1 is to have enough room for the traililng NUL byte (a NUL byte contains 0x00 and is often written as `'\0'`)  the `temp =` assigns the pointer to the allocated memory into the variable `temp` so `temp` now points to the allocated memory (eventually the code needs to call `free(temp)` to avoid a memory leak